# How can I load and delete Images from Firebase Storage in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

So I have the responsibility to make a listView which shows the user a list of images they add using their camera, they can naturally also remove a specific image by pressing a button which resides on the top right of each image, however the problem is that those images need to be stored and loaded from Firebase storage and I have no idea how I could go about doing that since the user needs to be able to remove those images from Firebase with the tap of a button and I need to display the ones that are left, I am relatively new to firebase storage and can't really wrap my head around what I could do to both load the correct images and remove the ones the user wants removed.

Any help would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create a collection using Firestore to store the data about the images like the url for the uploaded file, and a flag isDeleted, that is set to true/false according the action of the user. You can create something like this:

```
class UserImage {

int index;
String imageUrl;
bool isDeleted;

}
```

Then after you need just query for the images with isDeleted to false, to show the images available, and the images isDeleted set to true, to show the images that were removed. But in fact you don't have to delete the images from the Firebase Storage.

Comment: Well I would but the problem is that I need to use Firebase storage and so I can only store the file/image itself with whichever name I choose

Comment: But when you create an app Firebase, by the console you can use both Firestore and the Storage. What you don't use the Firestore also? If by some weird pre-requisite you can't use the Firestore Database, then you can create a pattern to name your files using the user id and the status of the image. By example: img_<userId>_<isDeleted>.jpg. Then retrieve the images where the filename has a suffix with <isDeleted> equals 'false' to show the images for the user.